# Framework Web API reference upgrade causes .Net to fail

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, owin, webapi

I have an API developed with .Net Framework Web API v4.8. I've upgraded the following assemblies and set their redirects accordingly:

- Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0.0 -> 4.2.2.0
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.20622.1351 -> 5.3.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.1.0.0 -> 4.2.2.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 3.1.0.0 -> 4.2.2.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt 3.1.0.0 -> 4.2.2.0

However, when I call a valid API endpoint I get an IIS 404 response (not a .Net one). It states there's nothing listening at that location, suggesting to me the .Net handler has errored so badly it's completely crashed out and IIS is trying to handle the request instead. If I change the redirects back down to the old version then I see .Net error responses again. With the upgraded versions none of my debugging breakpoints get hit and there's no error logging done. Nothing in the event viewer either. The IIS log only records the endpoint I tried to reach and the 404 response code. How do I debug this to see what is going wrong with the references I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this in an Identity Server sample project, enabling the Katana logger is what's needed to see where the OWIN chain is falling down. Added this in Web.config and it recorded an issue with the validation of my access token's audience.

```
<configuration>
....
  <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" />

        <sources>
            <source name="Microsoft.Owin">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="KatanaListener" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>

        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="KatanaListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="katana.trace.log" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
        </sharedListeners>

        <switches>
            <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose" />
        </switches>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```